# Index on calculated column triggers 900 byte index size limit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with a calculated VARCHAR column that will contain up to 106 characters:

```
CREATE TABLE report (
    report_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI NOT NULL,
    city_id VARCHAR(6) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI,

    unique_name AS
    CASE
        WHEN city_id IS NULL
        THEN name
        ELSE name + REPLICATE(' ', 100 - LEN(name)) + city_id
    END COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI,

    CONSTRAINT report_pk PRIMARY KEY (report_id)
);

/* Report name is unique per city (and among city-less rows) */
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX report_idx1 ON report (unique_name);
```

But when I run the statement I get this warning:

> Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'report_idx1'
>   has maximum length of 8000 bytes. For some combination of large
>   values, the insert/update operation will fail.

Is there a way to tell SQL Server that the column will not go beyond 106 characters so I get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `CAST(CASE ... END AS VARCHAR(106))`...

```
CAST(CASE
    WHEN city_id IS NULL
    THEN name
    ELSE name + REPLICATE(' ', 100 - LEN(name)) + city_id
END AS VARCHAR(106)) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI
```

or simply ignore it... It's only a warning.

Comment: It's simple and it works like a charm, thank you. *(I prefer to fix all warnings so those that really need attention don't go unnoticed in the script output.)*